# How do you read an input value to a desired amount of digits after the decimal point?

Tags: c

What I am saying is that lets say the user inputs a floating point number for ex 4.624.
Then you you have to read this value using scanf and then you might use it to do some sort of calculation by plugging it in a formula or something similar. How can you read that number to two digits after the decimal point which in this case would be 4.62 so that's the number you use in the formula and not the whole number of 4.624.

Comment: What if the input is `4.628`?  Should this be interpreted as `4.62` or `4.63`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
float x = 4.624;

float x_truncated_to_two_decimal_places = floor(x*100.0) / 100.0;
```

or

```
float x_rounded_to_two_decimal_places = round(x*100.0) / 100.0;
```

depending on what you want.

Comment: @Joker jbat100's answer shows the steps you take after you've received input via `scanf`.  `scanf("%f, &x); x = floor(x*100.0)/100.0;`

Comment: @Joker No, obviously. This is straight C code, not a format string. Just scan the value as you would scan it normally, using `%f`, then apply the technique presented here to obtain an appropriately rounded value.

Comment: @Joker scan a float in (without decimal place limitation) and then treat the result.

Comment: @Joker, to truncate use floor(), as in the first option